# Copy MATLAB object of a handle class

Tags: matlab

I've implemented a handle class in MATLAB, and I've tried to copy an object of the class by calling the following two functions:

```
objByteArray = getByteStreamFromArray(obj);
newObj = getArrayFromByteStream(objByteArray);
```

But from time to time I get the following error:

> Error using getArrayFromByteStream
>   Unable to read data stream because the data contains a bad version or endian-key

Is there another way to copy an object of a handle class?

Comment: Why would you be trying to use undocumented internal functionality, that's intended for saving a class to a binary file, just to copy a variable? What's wrong with just `newcopyofobj = obj`?

Comment: For handle objects (unlike value-class objects) `newcopyofobj = obj` just creats a reference to the old obj.
The class I'm talking about is inherited from handle.
Sorry, I wasn't clear enought. @SamRoberts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with a handle class, you can inherit your class from `matlab.mixin.Copyable`, which will give your class a customizable `copy` method.

By default, the `copy` method will implement a shallow copy of the class properties (i.e. if the class properties are themselves handle classes, the copies will be references to the original properties), but you can customize the copy operation to implement a deep copy (i.e. a copy operation is performed on the class properties as well).

Documentation for [`matlab.mixin.Copyable`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html).

Comment: Thanks @MarioKoddenbrock. If the answer helps you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer. This helps others to find it.